# Web Api 2 - Forwarding a request doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am implementing a payment system that only posts to public IPs and it's creating issues with development.

For that reason I am hosting a proxy controller on the UAT server that accepts the request and forwards it to the appropriate development machine.

So the controller is a bit like this:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ListenerProxy([FromUri] DepositResponse response)
    {
        // If request is targetted towards a developer machine, reroute the request to that machine directly.
        if (response.customField1 == "localhost")
        {
            // Re-route to  machine name
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var forwardedQuery = Request.RequestUri.Query.Replace("customField1=localhost", "customField1=forwarded");
                var localPath = Request.RequestUri.LocalPath.Replace("/api", "/myapi");
                string absoluteUrl = $"http://{response.customField2}{localPath}{forwardedQuery}";
                var proxyRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(Request.Method, absoluteUrl);
                foreach (var header in Request.Headers)
                {
                    proxyRequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }

                await httpClient.SendAsync(proxyRequest); //Doesn't work
                return ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Moved));
            }
        }

        return await StartDeposit(response);
    }
```

At this point `absoluteUrl` is correct and if I grab the value of it and add it directly on my browser, the request gets handled locally without issues.

However doing it programmatically with `httpClient.SendAsync(proxyRequest)` doesn't do it. Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to do `await httpClient.SendAsync(proxyRequest);`.

Comment: That's not true. It had the await before. I removed it to see if it makes any difference. It doesn't

Comment: It does make a difference. Just because it didn't fix your total problem doesn't make it not a problem. `SendAsync()` returns a task. If you don't await it, then nothing happens.

Comment: I'll add it back but the question remains

Comment: Try assigning the result of your send to a variable and check the status code.

Comment: await httpClient.GetAsync(absoluteUrl); worked!!

Comment: That tells me your `Request.Method` was wrong somehow. Perhaps you were doing a POST to the original endpoint? Either way, glad you got it working!